# Calculating the doppler shift between a satellite receiver and ground station transmitter with python

Tags: aerospace-engineering, rf-electronics

I'm trying to write a python script calculate the doppler shift that occurs between a satellite receiver and ground station transmitter. Below are the examples that I've been following . What I don't understand is what they expect for elevation. I understand that azimuth is an angle referenced from true north, but wouldn't elevation angle only apply to the ground station transmitter?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to provide a proper citation for the quoted material. That way we know to never bother with that book. That is the worst explanation I've ever seen. Start over. Find a decent reference.

Comment: Try here. See under "radio science tools". Read the documentation on the relevant kernels. SPICE documentation is usually pretty good. https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/SPICE_aware_Tools_List.pdf